# Hyundai can't remove key

Tags: electrical, hyundai, ignition-key

When switching car off unable to get key from the switch. The switch will not go past acc. point. Remove  battery ground cable then able to switch to lock position and  remove key.

Answer (score 1):

Hyundai makes lots of different models. Do a search for shift interlock problems on your year, make, model. That's what the system is called.